# Why can't I push this information from one react component to another?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, react-props

Still getting used to React and wrapping my head around using props properly.

But essentially I have this react component and i'm trying to take all the information in "drinkInfo" and use props to send it all to the CardInfo component so I can render it there. Yet i'm getting "Props is not defined" and i'm not really sure why.

```js
class Render  extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
  }

componentDidMount() {
    // call the drinks endpoint (via axios)
      let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: MYURL,
      };

    // let drinks = array of drinks
      let drinksFromDatabase =  [];
    // axios request
      axios.request(options)
        .then( (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          drinksFromDatabase =  response.data
          console.log("Drinks from Database are:")
          console.log(drinksFromDatabase)

          this.setState({ drinks : drinksFromDatabase})
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

render() {
    
    console.log("this.state is",[this.state])
    let stateArray = [this.state]

    if (stateArray[0] == null) {
      console.log("returning with nthing")
      return <div></div>
    }


  let firstElement = stateArray[0];
  let drinks = firstElement.drinks; 

  let drinkChoice = this.props.reduxState.drinkChoice
  console.log("Drink Choice is: " , drinkChoice)

  let drinkInfo = {
    type: props.drinks.type,
    name:  props.drinks.name,
    manufacturer: props.drinks.manufacturer,
    rating: props.drinks.rating,
    date: props.drinks.date,
    description: props.drinks.description,
    favorite: props.drinks.favorite
  }

  console.log("Drink info is: " , drinkInfo)

  let cardComponents = drinks.map((drink) =>{
    if (drink.type === drinkChoice) {
      return (<InfoCard {props.drinkInfo} />)
    } else {
      return <div>Nothing to Report</div>
    }})

  return (
      <div>
          <div>{cardComponents}</div>
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default Render
```

Comment: I think you are trying to get into very complicated territories without understanding basic JavaScript here. The variable `props` is undefined where you are trying to define `drinkInfo`

Comment: I know, the error tells me that much. I'm trying to learn. Can you give me more direction then that? Thank you!

Comment: you need to define `props`, if it is `this.props` that you are looking for, something like `const props = this.props` will do it for you

Comment: I see that now. Thank you. Now it's telling me that "props.drinks" is undefined. But if I console log just just "drinks" by itself I get the data I am trying to pass. Any idea why putting props in front of it would turn it undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are passing in props to your component. But you are getting the response for your drinks after the component has mounted with ComponentDidMount().

Within ComponentDidMount() this.SetState({drinks: drinksFromDatabase}) is initialized so when you console.log(drinks), the drinks state is logged.

You may want to re-read the docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

on props and states.  Since you set the state you will need to change:

```
let drinkInfo = {
    type: props.drinks.type,
    name:  props.drinks.name,
    manufacturer: props.drinks.manufacturer,
    rating: props.drinks.rating,
    date: props.drinks.date,
    description: props.drinks.description,
    favorite: props.drinks.favorite
  }
```

to:

```
let drinkInfo = {
        type: this.state.drinks.type,
        name:  this.state.drinks.name,
        manufacturer: this.state.drinks.manufacturer,
        rating: this.state.drinks.rating,
        date: this.state.drinks.date,
        description: this.state.drinks.description,
        favorite: this.state.drinks.favorite
      }
```

Since you're iterating by using drinks.map(drink => {...}) you can send the values of each iterable drink within the component:

```
let cardComponents = drinks.map((drink) =>{
    if (drink.type === drinkChoice) {
      return (<InfoCard props={drinkInfo} />)
    } else {
      return <div>Nothing to Report</div>
    }})
```

You then can access the props from your InfoCard props...  but honestly drinkInfo seems to contain the same info as your state drink so I'm not sure why you create an object of an objects values which you can then change the former to:

```
let cardComponents = drinks.map((drink) =>{
    if (drink.type === drinkChoice) {
      return (<InfoCard props={this.state.drinks} />)
    } else {
      return <div>Nothing to Report</div>
    }})
```

Which would pass all your drink values without having to create another object. Hopefully, this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Dude, this was so damn helpful. You don't know how much I appreciate you taking the time to lay things out for me. I will go through docs again for sure. Some of these concepts are still a little abstract so i'm trying to learn by doing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you are using react class component, so you forgot adding `this` to access the props.

```
this.props.drinks.type
this.props.drinks.name
 .....
```

Comment: I see that now. Thank you. Now it's telling me that "props.drinks" is undefined. But if I console log just just "drinks" by itself I get the data I am trying to pass. Any idea why putting props in front of it would turn it undefined?

Comment: are you sure you are getting drink from props ? because at this line `this.setState({ drinks : drinksFromDatabase})` you are trying to update un state called `drinks`. if it's so, then you should do `this.state.drinks.type`. i think you need to refer to the React doc https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html , state and props basics